# Duplication check before saving the form data in Django

Tags: django, forms

I got a form as following:

```
class CourseAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
  """Add a new course"""
  name = forms.CharField(label=_("Course Name"), max_length=100)
  description = forms.Textarea()
  course_no = forms.CharField(label=_("course Number"), max_length=15)


  #Attach a form helper to this class
  helper = FormHelper()
  helper.form_id = "addcourse"
  helper.form_class = "course"

  #Add in a submit and reset button
  submit = Submit("Add", "Add New Record")
  helper.add_input(submit)
  reset = Reset("Reset", "Reset")
  helper.add_input(reset)

def clean(self):
  """ 
  Override the default clean method to check whether this course has been already inputted.
  """    
  cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
  name = cleaned_data.get('name')
  hic = cleaned_data.get('course_no')

  try:
    course=Course.objects.get(name=name)
  except Course.DoesNotExist:
    course=None

  if course:
    msg = u"Course name: %s has already exist." % name
    self._errors['name'] = self.error_class([msg])
    del cleaned_data['name']
    return cleaned_data
  else:
    return self.cleaned_data

  class Meta:
    model = Course
```

As you can see I overwrote the clean method to check whether this course has already existed in the database when the user is trying to add it. This works fine for me.

However, when I want to add the same check for the form for editing, the problem happened. Because it is editing, so the record with same course name has already exist in the DB. Thus, the same check would throw error the course name has already exist. But I need to check the duplication in order to avoid the user updating the course name to another already existed course name.

I am thinking of checking the value of the course name to see if it is changed. If it has been changed, than I can do the same check as above. If it has not been changed, I don't need to do the check. But I don't know how can I obtain the origin data for editing.

Does anyone know how to do this in Django?

My view looks as following:

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
@custom_permission_required('records.change_course', 'course')
def edit_course(request,course_id):
  # See if the family exists:
try:
  course = Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
except Course.DoesNotExist:
  course = None

if course:
  if request.method == 'GET':
    form = CourseEditForm(instance=course)
    return render_to_response('records/add.html',
                            {'form': form},
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                            )
  elif request.method == 'POST':
    form = CourseEditForm(request.POST, instance=course)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/records/')
    # form is not valid: 
    else:
      error_message = "Please correct all values marked in red."
      return render_to_response('records/edit.html', 
                              {'form': form, 'error_message': error_message},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                              )      
else:
  error = "Course %s does not exist. Press the 'BACK' button on your browser." % (course)
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('DigitalRecords.views.error', args=(error,)))
```

Thank you.

Comment: what does your view look like? Are you using the `instance` argument to populate the model form with a DB object when editing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should just set `unique=True` on the `Course.name` field and let the framework handle that validation for you.

**Update:**

Since `unique=True` is not the right answer for your case, you can check this way:

```
def clean(self):
    """ 
    Override the default clean method to check whether this course has
    been already inputted.
    """    
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    name = cleaned_data.get('name')

    matching_courses = Course.objects.filter(name=name)
    if self.instance:
        matching_courses = matching_courses.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
    if matching_courses.exists():
        msg = u"Course name: %s has already exist." % name
        raise ValidationError(msg)
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data

class Meta:
    model = Course
```

As a side note, I've also changed your custom error handling to use a more standard `ValidationError`.

Comment: The point is that I allow same course name in the database if the course is under different departments. I want to do the check to avoid same course name under the same department.

Comment: If I want to check validation on two matching fields at the same time, What i need to do extra in it?

Answer (score 3):

I believe excluding the current instance id from the results would solve the problem:

```
from django.db.models import Q
try:
    qs = Course.objects.filter(name=self.cleaned_data.get('name'))
    if self.instance.pk is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(~Q(pk=self.instance.pk))
    course = qs.get()
except Course.DoesNotExist:
    course = None
```

However as dokkaebi pointed out, unique is really the better way to go with this, as this solution is vulnerable to race conditions. I'm not sure what your datamodel looks like but I suspect defining

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('department', 'name')
```

should accomplish what you want.

Comment: `unique_together` FTW. Never assume that your data will only ever be altered by a particular webpage. The only safe way to protect data integrity is to enforce it at the database whenever possible.