# Checking duplicate objects before saving

Tags: django

Good day SO:

How to check if items are duplicate before saving? I got an answer similar to my question but I need to add a validation also who created the item. The answer that I am currently using is from this [SO Answer by @dokkaebi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12961270/7434025). It is currently working, however, if other users also created the same record, I would like them to be able to do so. Only limit this to the current user.

What I did was:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    job_title = cleaned_data.get("job_title")
    others = cleaned_data.get("others")

    matching_job_item = PropositionItem.objects.filter(job_title=job_title, others=others)
    if self.instance:
        matching_job_item = matching_job_item.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk, status="0")
    if matching_job_item.exists():
        msg = u"Job Tile: %s has already exist." % job_title
        raise forms.ValidationError(msg)
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data
```

What I want: User A can't create a duplicate item while User B can create what user A created but only once.

Comment: Can you link the user info with the instance you are using in def clean()?

Comment: That is currently what I am trying to do but I am still checking the net how to do so.

Comment: You must have setup users? Separate logins for users using django User class maybe?

Comment: @rodjames Don't you just want two / more fields to be unique together? You can use a [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) for that. Also you should pass an unsaved model instance with the user set to it to the form just so the user is included in the validation. Leave the rest to the form (it calls `validate_unique` on the instance).

Comment: I actually want them to be unique with 5 fields, 6 if I include the user. RN I got my form working by importing my userID to my form. It just took a while to import. I also read unique_together but I was not able to make it work on my app.